# How to automate the exchange section when using google finance formula in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, share, price

I am trying to build a very basic google sheet where Columns A -  D will be the following:
Share name  Share code  Exchange    Current Price

For Column D (Current Price) - I want to be able to get the live share price using =GOOGLEFINANCE, but the bit I am struggling to get working is for the formula: =GOOGLEFINANCE("ASX:BHP") - I want to be able to automate the "ASX" to column 3 (C3 on this occasion).

The closest I got to is =GOOGLEFINANCE(""C3":BHP"), but it's giving me an error. Would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=GOOGLEFINANCE(C3&":BHP")
```